# What's the use of widget id on wxpython?

Tags: wxpython

I've been trying to learn wxpython and I see this id when creating widgets like:

```
menubar = wx.MenuBar()
file = wx.Menu()
file.Append(-1, 'Quit', 'Quit application')
menubar.Append(file, '&File')
```

I've read something that says when it is set to -1, its automatically generated but what's the real use of id and how will it be useful to the event?

Comment: For identify the item.
For Example: can Delete the menu item from the menu by provide item ID.

Comment: Yeah, I figured after a while of posting this. thanks anyway.

Comment: @whunmr, perhaps you should add that as an answer, so the OP can accept it as a solution. Its not *that* obvious to those who start out with wxPython

Comment: @Ivo Flipse It really isn't. Which is why I'm here :D Are there any other uses for them?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

ID is for identification, and is used internally by wxPython to track widgets and bind events or emit events etc BUT most of the time as a user of wxPython you don't need to set or use ID in any place, because most of the time you will be using python objects to refer to widgets not the IDs e.g.

```
>>> btn = wx.Button(win, label="click me")
>>> btn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, on_click)
```

So you don't need to set ID to anything or need to refer it.